# Why models are named "user.rb" and not "user_model.rb"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Why controllers are named "users_controller.rb" and models are not named "user_model.rb"?

Why there is "application_controller.rb" but inside views the folder "layout" is not named "application"?

Comment: Actually, the `app/views` dir contains a `layouts` directory which contains an `application.html.erb` file that is the application layout.

Comment: why is it so important anyway? if they will be anmed ###_model.rb will it help you code better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code flows from thought best when the naming supports the developers internal model of the problem.  When building an application, I don't think of finding a user model (`UserModel.find`) I think of finding a user (`User.find`).  On the other hand, the controllers are the translation layer between the web interface and the data store (and business logic), so it makes more sense to call them something different.

There's also the problem of namespacing; if both my model and controller are named User, then which User am I referring to at any given moment?  In this case, either you name everything with their type, which runs into the problem I describe above, or one 'wins' and is allowed to be referenced 'bare'. It seems to make the most sense that the model would win, so as to provide a better mental mapping.

Inside `app/views/layout` is `application.html.erb` and you can have other layouts which are selected by different controllers.

In the end, however, these were choices made during the development of Rails, and they are entirely stylistic choices based on what the developers thought made the most sense, so there isn't really a 'right' answer to your question, unfortunately.  In fact, some similar decisions have been revisited.  (`application_controller.rb` used to just be named `application.rb`.)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails follows ["Convention over configuration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) principle. Particularly naming conventions are extensively used by Rails while mapping your routes to controllers, auto-loading and reloading classes, finding appropriate template for an action and many other features.

That principle leads to some restrictions as you can't easily break some of the conventions without getting into troubles. But on the other hand it makes our lives easier as we get smaller amount of configuration and can easily move from one Rails project to the other because all of them have similar structure and follow same conventions. In addition, I believe, that makes Rails core development much easier as core team have a lot of information about how the project using Rails will be structured and they don't have to worry that much about generalization. They simply assume you play by the rules and follow conventions.

Though, I doubt many of naming conventions have serious reasoning behind them. I think at some point someone just decided that it'd be easier for Rails to handle your controllers and distinguish them from other classes if they all have `Controller` suffix. And here we are having all our controllers in `app/controllers` directory with that suffix.